# How to avoid sub-optimal pagebreaks that are inserted before a new section/subsection?

Tags: page-breaking

I am using the `book` documentclass for my PhD thesis. The document is typeset by the `luatex` engine from TL2018.

I get unnecessary pagebreaks at the end of a section or subsection. Even when it appears (to my eye) that the next section heading as well as a couple of lines from the opening paragraph of next section can still fit into the same page.

The end result is that almost 25-30% of the page ending a section is blank and leads to an unnecessary increase in the overall page count. I tried the `\nopagebreak` option with counts all the way upto 4, but TeX does not obey these and retains the current behavior which seems sub-optimal to the eye.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)... There are packages that result in this problem, but this is not default behaviour.

Comment: @samcarter Will do so. I shall try to remove packages one by one and see when and where this problem occurs. But I don't completely buy that TeX is not to blame. The K-P algorithm is only for optimal line-breaking within each paragraph, and not for globally optimised pagination. I think TeX even typesets each page individually, and once that page is typeset, it is done. See Frank Mittelbach's answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

Comment: Try `\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-4]

\section{title}

\lipsum
\end{document}` Tex has no problem with placing sections in the bottom 30% of a page.